# ReactJS: useEffect is not run when the url changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS website, and I'm still a noob using it.

I've 2 Components

- The first one is the `/` page, that must be rendered after a request to a web server, when the user get to that route, I've used useEffect for this.
- The second one is the `/mostraMaterie/:id` that must be rendered after another request to the web server.

The first component work like a charm, whereas the second one doesn't trigger the useEffect function.

When the user clicks a button on the `/` component, it is redirected to `/mostraMateria/:id` with the according id.

The problem is the `/mostraMateria` component I have another useEffect function, but it is not triggered.

As suggested in the comment, this is the mostraMateria file in JSFiddle
[mostraMaterie.js](https://jsfiddle.net/DavideVito/mcv4zou6/3/)

**App.js**
handles the user connection

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MostraMaterie from "./Contenuti/MostraMaterie";
import "./App.css";

import Main from "./Contenuti/Main";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/mostraMateria/:id" component={MostraMaterie} />{" "}
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />{" "}
      </Switch>{" "}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Main.js** 
handles the page rendering if the location is `/` and work perfectly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Indirizzi from "./Indirizzi";
import Bottone from "../Util/Bottone";
import "../App.css";
import FullNavBar from "../NavBar/FullNavBar";

function Main() {
  const [indirizzi, cambiaIndirizzi] = useState([]);

  const fetchIndirizzi = () => {
    async function prendiIndirizzi() {
      let indirizzi = await fetch(
        "https://vps.lellovitiello.tk/Riassunty/API/indirizzi.php"
      );
      let ind = await indirizzi.json();

      for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i++) {
        async function prendiMaterie() {
          let materie = await fetch(
            `https://vps.lellovitiello.tk/Riassunty/API/materie.php?indirizzo=${ind[i].Indirizzo}`
          );
          materie = await materie.json();

          for (let materia of materie) {
            Object.defineProperty(
              materia,
              "nome",
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(materia, "Materia")
            );
            delete materia["Materia"];

            Object.defineProperty(
              materia,
              "id",
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(materia, "IDMateria")
            );
            delete materia["IDMateria"];
            delete materia["Indirizzo"];
          }

          Object.defineProperty(
            ind[i],
            "nome",
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ind[i], "Indirizzo")
          );
          delete ind[i]["Indirizzo"];
          Object.assign(ind[i], { dati: materie });
          Object.assign(ind[i], { id: i });
        }

        await prendiMaterie();
      }
      console.log("Main.js", ind);
      cambiaIndirizzi(ind);
    }
    prendiIndirizzi();
  };
  useEffect(fetchIndirizzi, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FullNavBar elementi={indirizzi} />{" "}
      <Link to="/Login">
        <Bottone TestoBottone="Per caricare un riassunto" />
      </Link>{" "}
      {indirizzi.map(indirizzo => {
        console.log(indirizzo);
        return <Indirizzi dati={indirizzo} />;
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

**MostraMaterie.js**
handles the page rendering if the location is `/mostraMaterie/:id` and doesn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../App.css";
import history from "../Util/history";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import FullNavBar from "../NavBar/FullNavBar";
import Indirizzi from "./Indirizzi";
import Bottone from "../Util/Bottone";

function MostraMaterie(props) {
  const [anni, cambiaAnni] = useState([]);

  // *** this function is never called ***
  const fetchAnni = () => {
    async function prendiAnni() {
      let anniJson = await fetch(
        "https://vps.lellovitiello.tk/Riassunty/API/ottieniAnni.php"
      );
      let idMateria = props.match.params.id;
      let ann = [];
      anniJson = await anniJson.json();

      for (let anno of anniJson) {
        async function prendiAnteprime() {
          let anteprimeFetch = await fetch(
            `https://vps.lellovitiello.tk/Riassunty/API/anteprima.php?idMateria=${idMateria}&anno=${anno}`
          );

          anteprimeFetch = await anteprimeFetch.json();
          for (let anteprima of anteprimeFetch) {
            Object.defineProperty(
              anteprima,
              "nome",
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(anteprima, "Titolo")
            );

            Object.defineProperty(
              anteprima,
              "id",
              Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(anteprima, "ID")
            );
            delete anteprima["Titolo"];
            delete anteprima["ID"];
          }

          let annoOggetto = {
            nome: anno + "",
            anteprime: anteprimeFetch
          };
          ann.push(annoOggetto);
        }

        await prendiAnteprime();
      }
      debugger;
      cambiaAnni(ann);
    }
    console.log("Vengo eseguito");
    prendiAnni();
  };

  useEffect(fetchAnni, []); 
  console.log(history.location);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <FullNavBar indirizzi={anni} />{" "}
      <Link to="/Login">
        <Bottone TestoBottone="Per caricare un riassunto" />
      </Link>{" "}
      <h1> CIao CIAO CIAO CIAOC </h1>{" "}
      {
        //*** this depends on the response of the web server ***
         anni.map(anno => {
              console.log("Ciao");
              return <Indirizzi dati={anno} />;
            })}{" "}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default MostraMaterie;
```

How can I make this work?

**Edit**

I've remove the `<FullNavBar indirizzi={anni} />{" "}` and it works, now my request is made to the server and the ``fetchAnni``` function in fired.

The problem is, I need the piece of code I removed, it seems that the 
`<FullNavBar indirizzi={anni} />{" "}` is rendered before the call of `fetchAnni`, even adding the `await prendiAnni` and `async fetchAnni`  as suggested by [Artur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2929632/arthur) doesn't work.

I've also changed from `useEffect(fetchAnni, []);` to `useEffect(fetchAnni, [props.location.pathname]);` that is a string

Comment: Your code is quite long, maybe make a simple jsfiddle for others to play around with so they can help you better. 
FWIW, my guess is that you need to add the history.location to the second param of the useEffect in your mostraMaterie component. Then the useEffect is fired also when the history object changes.  (Although, performance issues?)

Comment: I've tried to add the [history.location] as second parameter to useEffect and still doesn't work.

Comment: `history.location` is an object, useEffect second params should be used only with an array of primitive varible (string, number, ...) so you should select primitive field you're using on useEffect (like `props.match.params.id`)

Comment: One suggestion, for the perfomance sake try to use useMemo to avoid redundant recalculations.

Answer (score 10):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react' 
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const Root = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        history.listen((location) => {
            console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`)
        })
    }, [history])
}
```

Comment: Simple and working fine. Thank you.

Comment: useHistory is now deprecated, useNavigate should be preferred instead

Answer (score 5):

**Second useEffect arg `[]` :**

First of all: Sending a `[]` as second arg of useEffect will say "NEVER RE-RUN this function" (only 2times, on mount and on unmount).

**Removing it ! it's NO :**

You do not want to remove it or your effect will be called on every render and cause performances issues.

**Choosing the right var(s) to track:**

You have to give React all the fields who will affect the re-render of your function, in your case "when the URL change".

**Hint:** React will test every time if one of variable has been update since last render, but we als know that non-primitive will not works:

```
const a = {name: "Foo"};
const b = {name: "Foo"};
const res = (a === b); // False
```

So, you have to choose for primitive values only. In your case the simplest is the `/:id` on your Route: `props.match.params.id`.

```
  useEffect(fetchAnni, [props.match.params.id]); 
  console.log(`Render for ID: ${props.match.params.id}`);
```

---

**Async/Await**

Also, you're function `prendiAnni` is defined as `async` but you call it:

```
console.log("Vengo eseguito");
prendiAnni();
```

Instead of

```
await prendiAnni();
```

Comment: Thank for the long explanation, as soon as I‘ve some free time I will try. I’ve called without the ```await ``` keyword, because I need to make the whole function as ```async ``` and when passing as useEffect param, react will throw a warning in the console.

Answer (score 4):

Include the URL in the dependencies array of the `useEffect` Hook.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    
    const url = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

    useEffect(() => {
    
        // Function will retrigger on URL change

    }, [url]);

    return(
        <div className = 'Whatever'>Whatever</div>
    );

}

export default Component;
```

Comment: Will this work? How does React know to do a rerender to even begin to check the useEffect? Unless the URL is coming from something like ReactRouter... right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you are passing an empty array as your second argument to useEffect(), `useEffect(fetchAnni, []);`

From https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run.

If you want to run the effect on every render, you can leave off the second argument. If you want it to only run when certain props/state values change, you can pass those as array values in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

the code I_love_vegetables has made works but useHistory has been deprecated in react-router-dom v6 so use useNavigate