# React useEffect is not triggering on link to route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have the following code within a component called `AllJobs`

```
                            <TableCell>
                                    <Link
                                        to={`/job/${item.id}`}
                                        style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', color: 'black' }}
                                    >             
                                     {item.id}
                                    </Link>
                            </TableCell>
```

When the user clicks on this link, it then calls the component `JobDetails` as per below route, within my App.js file:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/job/:id">
      <JobDetails />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

My problem is, within my `JobDetails` component, I have a useEffect that isn't being fired and unsure why it isn't as I need it to call my `getJob()` function?

```
export default function JobDetails() {

const { id } = useParams();

const [currentJob, setCurrentJob] = useState([]);

const getJob = async () => {
    console.log("Inside JobDetails for id:", id)
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/get-job/${id}`);
      const currentJobRec = await response.json();
      console.log("current-job", currentJobRec)
          
      setCurrentJob(currentJobRec);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  }; 

  useEffect(() => {
    getJob();
  }, []);
```

Can anyone please assist as to what I am missing as I need to trigger off the useEffect().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: useEffect is not run when the url changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290004/reactjs-useeffect-is-not-run-when-the-url-changes)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the way you set up your Routes and Links are very correct. I honestly am not entirely sure what the exact problem is, but I suggest this:

Reruns the effect/`getJob()` again whenever the `id` parameter changes: Add `id` to your dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    getJob();
  }, [id]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't trigger the effect.

Answer (score -2):

This is the classic gotcha. You can trigger the `getJob` like this:

```
// IIFE
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await getJob())();
}, []);
```

**Now to the reason, why async call does not work in useEffect ?**

First, let's look at useEffect from React docs.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
  return () => {
    // Clean up the subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
});
```

Notice, this returns a function (cleanup function). This function is executed when component unmount (incase of empty dependency array).

Now going back to your example

```
useEffect(() => {
    getJob();
}, []);
```

`getJob` is defined as an `async` function and is therefore bound to return a `Promise`. Thus instead of cleanup, the Promise is returned causing this mess.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation but unfortunately this still didn't work. The function getJob() is still not being called via useEffect. Could there be something to do with the `link to` route process?

Comment: I've added `await` in the IIFE. If that does not have any effect still, then check if the `JobDetails` is even being mounted.

Comment: This is not accurate at all. see: [React Hook Warnings for async function in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572588/13762301) for a clean explanation of async in useEffect

Comment: @pilchard I'm sorry to inform you that Dan's way is just another way. Both are correct.      
Imagine you have 5 async calls which you want to trigger inside a `useEffect` and they may even be called in other modules (hence an exported function).
Now, do you think it is a good idea defining the whole function in there?

Exactly, it isn't. So depending upon the use case we can make the decision. Also, I'll encourage you to not blindly go ahead with the examples you see. React is made to achieve one result by multiple ways.

Comment: Did you read the answer? It also covers using `useCallback()` and adding it to the dependency array. The point is you don't need an IIFE if you've already defined the function either inside or outside the useEffect. Plus the OP's problem is not async related, but route/mount related.

Comment: @ShravanDhar - unfortunately your updated solution didn't work either.